# express-validator: LHS Brackets

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

Is there a way to validate LHS Brackets in express-validator for advanced filterings?

Example querystring:

```
?test[gt]=1
```

Example validations i tried:

```
query("test.gt").isAlphanumeric()
query("test[gt]").isAlphanumeric()
```

seems not work

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs is what you need (i guess)

> **A querystring parsing and stringifying library with some added security.**

```js
var qs = require('qs');
var assert = require('assert');

assert.deepEqual(qs.parse('price[gte]=10&price[lte]=100'), {
    price: {
        gte: 10,
        lte: 100
    }
});
```

the example is taken from this blog post: https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/api-design/REST-API-Design-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pagination/#benefits